# Collapse phrase on loop directive of OpenACC works occasionally. Why?

Tags: nested-loops, openacc

I have an MD code that has 4 nested loops. Assuming that the loops are linear, the complexity of the code is `O(N^4)`.

Using OpenACC, potentially I can say to the compiler that collapse all of them into one using `collapse(4)` in my outer loop. However, it is not the case for all values of `N`. See below for the cases:

- When N=20 and I use `collapse(2)`, it works.
- When N=20 and I use `collapse(4)`, it works.
- When N=80 and I use `collapse(2)`, it works.
- When N=80 and I use `collapse(4)`, it **does not** work and gives me following error.

> Out of memory allocating 4045842432 bytes of device memory
>
> Failing in Thread:1
>
> total/free CUDA memory: 4291493888/2951409664
>
> Present table dump for device[1]: NVIDIA Tesla GPU 0, compute capability 5.2
>
> host:0x18bebe0 device:0x703dc0000 size:12 presentcount:0+1 line:22 name:s_species
>
> ...

What I am trying to say here is that when I increase my system size, I can not collapse to 4 levels anymore. What could be the reason?

Based on this observation, I might not be able to collapse for more than a certain amount of N, right?

Is this true? "The `collapse` number depends on the size of data."

**Updated by code and compiler feedback:**

```
#pragma acc parallel loop collapse(4) independent gang vector \
                present(s_boxes_nAtoms[0:s_boxes_nTotalBoxes], \
                        s_boxes_nbrBoxes_array[0:s_boxes_nLocalBoxes * nNbrBoxes], \
                        s_atoms_r[0:fsize][0:3],\
                        s_atoms_f[0:fsize][0:3],\
                        s_atoms_U[0:fsize],\
                        pot_rhobar[0:maxTotalAtoms],\
                        pot_dfEmbed[0:maxTotalAtoms],\
                        pot_rho_values[-1:1],\
                        pot_phi_values[-1:1]) \
                copyin(nNbrBoxes, rCut2)
    for (int iBox = 0; iBox < s_boxes_nLocalBoxes; iBox++) {

        // loop over neighbor boxes of iBox (some may be halo boxes)
#pragma acc loop independent
        for (int jTmp = 0; jTmp < nNbrBoxes; jTmp++) {

            // loop over atoms in iBox
#pragma acc loop independent
            for (int _iOff = 0; _iOff < MAXATOMS; _iOff++) {
                // loop over atoms in jBox
#pragma acc loop independent
                for (int _jOff = 0;_jOff < MAXATOMS; _jOff++) {

                    int nIBox = s_boxes_nAtoms[iBox];
                    int jBox = s_boxes_nbrBoxes_array[iBox * nNbrBoxes + jTmp];
                    int nJBox = s_boxes_nAtoms[jBox];

                    if(_iOff >= nIBox || _jOff >= nJBox)
                        continue;

                    int iOff = MAXATOMS * iBox + _iOff;
                    int jOff = MAXATOMS * jBox + _jOff;

                    real_t r2 = 0.0;
                    real3 dr;

                    dr[0] = s_atoms_r[iOff][0] - s_atoms_r[jOff][0];
                    dr[1] = s_atoms_r[iOff][1] - s_atoms_r[jOff][1];
                    dr[2] = s_atoms_r[iOff][2] - s_atoms_r[jOff][2];
                    r2 += dr[0] * dr[0];
                    r2 += dr[1] * dr[1];
                    r2 += dr[2] * dr[2];

                    if (r2 <= rCut2 && r2 > 0.0) {

                        real_t r = sqrt(r2);

                        real_t rhoTmp, dRho;
                        interpolate_acc(pot_rho_values, pot_rho_x0,
                                pot_rho_invDx, pot_rho_n, r, &rhoTmp, &dRho);

                        r = 1.0f / r;

                        s_atoms_f[iOff][0] -= (pot_dfEmbed[iOff]
                                + pot_dfEmbed[jOff]) * dRho * dr[0] * r;
                        s_atoms_f[iOff][1] -= (pot_dfEmbed[iOff]
                                + pot_dfEmbed[jOff]) * dRho * dr[1] * r;
                        s_atoms_f[iOff][2] -= (pot_dfEmbed[iOff]
                                + pot_dfEmbed[jOff]) * dRho * dr[2] * r;

                    }

                } // loop over atoms in jBox
            } // loop over atoms in iBox
        } // loop over neighbor boxes
    } // loop over local boxes
```

And the **runtime** feedback is:

```
Out of memory allocating 258933915648 bytes of device memory
Failing in Thread:1
total/free CUDA memory: 4291493888/2885210112
Present table dump for device[1]: NVIDIA Tesla GPU 0, compute capability 5.2
host:0x2502be0 device:0x703dc0000 size:12 presentcount:0+1 line:22 name:s_species
host:0x2504b00 device:0x733b81000 size:2012 presentcount:0+1 line:-1 name:(null)
host:0x25052f0 device:0x733b80800 size:2012 presentcount:1+1 line:-1 name:(null)
host:0x2505ae0 device:0x733b80000 size:2012 presentcount:1+1 line:-1 name:(null)
host:0x7f967d686010 device:0x7306c0000 size:55296000 presentcount:1+1 line:249 name:pot_rhobar
host:0x7f9680b43010 device:0x72d200000 size:55296000 presentcount:1+1 line:248 name:pot_dfEmbed
host:0x7f96883df010 device:0x703fc0000 size:23328000 presentcount:1+1 line:28 name:s_boxes_nbrBoxes
host:0x7f9694038010 device:0x7232c0000 size:55296000 presentcount:1+1 line:45 name:s_atoms_U
host:0x7f96974f5010 device:0x719480000 size:165888000 presentcount:1+1 line:45 name:s_atoms_f
host:0x7f96a132a010 device:0x70f640000 size:165888000 presentcount:0+1 line:45 name:s_atoms_p
host:0x7f96ab15f010 device:0x705800000 size:165888000 presentcount:1+1 line:45 name:s_atoms_r
host:0x7f96b4f94010 device:0x726880000 size:55296000 presentcount:0+1 line:45 name:s_atoms_iSpecies
host:0x7f96b8451010 device:0x729d40000 size:55296000 presentcount:0+1 line:45 name:s_atoms_gid
host:0x7f96bda84010 device:0x726780000 size:864000 presentcount:1+1 line:45 name:s_boxes_nAtoms
host:0x7ffe3146bc60 device:0x703dc0400 size:4 presentcount:1+0 line:418 name:nNbrBoxes
host:0x7ffe3146bd2c device:0x703dc0200 size:4 presentcount:1+0 line:418 name:rCut2
allocated block device:0x703dc0000 size:512 thread:1
allocated block device:0x703dc0200 size:512 thread:1
allocated block device:0x703dc0400 size:512 thread:1
allocated block device:0x703fc0000 size:23328256 thread:1
allocated block device:0x705800000 size:165888000 thread:1
allocated block device:0x70f640000 size:165888000 thread:1
allocated block device:0x719480000 size:165888000 thread:1
allocated block device:0x7232c0000 size:55296000 thread:1
allocated block device:0x726780000 size:864256 thread:1
allocated block device:0x726880000 size:55296000 thread:1
allocated block device:0x729d40000 size:55296000 thread:1
allocated block device:0x72d200000 size:55296000 thread:1
allocated block device:0x7306c0000 size:55296000 thread:1
allocated block device:0x733b80000 size:2048 thread:1
allocated block device:0x733b80800 size:2048 thread:1
allocated block device:0x733b81000 size:2048 thread:1
call to cuMemAlloc returned error 2: Out of memory
```

And, here is the compiler feedback:

```
pgcc  -c99  -acc -ta=nvidia -Minfo=accel -DSINGLE -DNDEBUG -mp -O3 -fast -Minline -Munroll=c:4 -Mlre -Mpre -Mprefetch   -c eam.c -o eam.o
eamForce:
    248, Generating enter data copyin(pot_dfEmbed[:maxTotalAtoms])
    249, Generating enter data copyin(pot_rhobar[:maxTotalAtoms])
    302, Generating present(pot_dfEmbed[:maxTotalAtoms],pot_rhobar[:maxTotalAtoms],s_atoms_U[:fsize],s_atoms_f[:fsize][:])
         Accelerator kernel generated
         Generating Tesla code
        309, #pragma acc loop gang, vector(128) /* blockIdx.x threadIdx.x */
    317, Generating copyin(nNbrBoxes)
         Generating present(pot_phi_values[-1],pot_rho_values[-1],pot_rhobar[:maxTotalAtoms])
         Generating copyin(rCut2)
         Generating present(s_atoms_U[:fsize],s_atoms_f[:fsize][:],s_atoms_r[:fsize][:],s_boxes_nAtoms[:s_boxes_nTotalBoxes],s_boxes_nbrBoxes_array[:nNbrBoxes*s_boxes_nLocalBoxes])
         Accelerator kernel generated
         Generating Tesla code
        317, Generating reduction(+:etot)
        327, #pragma acc loop gang, vector(128) /* blockIdx.x threadIdx.x */
        332, #pragma acc loop seq
        338, #pragma acc loop seq collapse(2)
        341,   collapsed */
    332, Scalar last value needed after loop for etot at line 485
    338, Scalar last value needed after loop for etot at line 485
    341, Scalar last value needed after loop for etot at line 485
    384, Generating present(pot_dfEmbed[:maxTotalAtoms],pot_f_values[-1],pot_rhobar[:maxTotalAtoms],s_atoms_U[:fsize],s_atoms_f[:fsize][:],s_boxes_nAtoms[:s_boxes_nTotalBoxes],s_boxes_nbrBoxes_array[:nNbrBoxes*s_boxes_nLocalBoxes])
         Accelerator kernel generated
         Generating Tesla code
        384, Generating reduction(+:etot)
        393, #pragma acc loop gang, vector(128) /* blockIdx.x threadIdx.x */
        398, #pragma acc loop seq
         398, Loop is parallelizable
    414, Generating update self(pot_dfEmbed[:maxTotalAtoms])
    422, Generating copyin(nNbrBoxes)
         Generating present(pot_dfEmbed[:maxTotalAtoms],pot_phi_values[-1],pot_rho_values[-1],pot_rhobar[:maxTotalAtoms])
         Generating copyin(rCut2)
         Generating present(s_atoms_U[:fsize],s_atoms_f[:fsize][:],s_atoms_r[:fsize][:],s_boxes_nAtoms[:s_boxes_nTotalBoxes],s_boxes_nbrBoxes_array[:nNbrBoxes*s_boxes_nLocalBoxes])
         Generating update device(pot_dfEmbed[:maxTotalAtoms])
         Accelerator kernel generated
         Generating Tesla code
        433, #pragma acc loop gang, vector(128) /* blockIdx.x threadIdx.x */
        438, #pragma acc loop seq
        444, #pragma acc loop seq
        448, #pragma acc loop seq
    438, Loop is parallelizable
    444, Loop is parallelizable
    448, Loop is parallelizable
pgcc  -c99  -acc -ta=nvidia -Minfo=accel -DSINGLE -DNDEBUG -mp -O3 -fast -Minline -Munroll=c:4 -Mlre -Mpre -Mprefetch   -o ../bin/CoMD-acc ljForce.o haloExchange.o linkCells.o yamlOutput.o performanceTimers.o timestep.o cmdLineParser.o decomposition.o mycommand.o initAtoms.o CoMD.o parallel.o eam.o random.o -lm
```

Comment: Do you have any "private" clauses on the loop?  "private" will create an array of these values in global memory so increasing the number of threads can sometimes cause out of memory errors.

Comment: No I don't have any `private` clause. But I do have a long `present` clause. However, inside the code, there are some local variables. On another note, when I decrease the amount of code inside the innermost loop, collapse works correctly.

Comment: Hmm.  I'm not sure then.  The amount of code in the loop shouldn't really matter.  Can you post the compiler feedback messages (-Minfo=accel) for the working and failing case?

Comment: Yes I can. Let me edit the question with my code and the compiler feedback.